# Is it possible to use GPU resources on Gingerbread for an app?

Tags: android, gpu, android-2.3-gingerbread

I'm creating an image processing app and would like to use the available GPU on my phone (running gingerbread). Is it possible to do so?

I googled a lot on this issue, but I couldnt find any answers, much to my surprise.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if the device supports GLES2, you can create a shader that implements the functionality. It would go something like:

- Create a fragment shader that implements the image processing.
- Create a texture holding the image you want to process and pass it to the shader.
- Pass parameters through uniforms or pack them into another texture and pass to the shader.
- Render to an frame buffer.
- Get the resulting image out via `glReadPixels`

Comment: Interesting article on using openCL on Android for ARM cores [here](http://www.pgroup.com/lit/articles/insider/v4n2a3.htm)